# Подхват значения из "произвольные поля". Помогите

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру кодинга.

Я попробовал реализовать задачу сам, но моих знаний явно недостаточно т.к. не программист :-(

В single.php шаблона Wordpress я хотел реализовать следующее:

если для конкретной страницы установлено значение "произвольного поля" `customcategory = Некая категория` и `customlink = exsample.ru\nekayakegoriya\`, то подхватывать их и выводить, а если их нет, то выводить код стандартных хлебных крошек.

```
<span class="archive-title">            
<?php
    $customcat = get_post_meta($post->ID, "customcategory", true);
    if ($customcat)
        '<div class="block-crumbs" prefix:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="https://exsample.ru/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Главная</a></span> » <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="https://'.$customlink.'">'.$customcategory.'</a></span>  »  <span class="current-crumbs"><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>'
   else 
        crumbs_breadcrumbs_new();
 ?>
</span>
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как правильно прописать команду.

Answer (score 1):

Получаете id страницы:

```
$id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Проверяете есть ли в wp_postmeta данные по этой странице и подставляете:

```
if(get_post_meta($id, "customcategory", true) && get_post_meta($id, "customlink", true)){ ?>
    '<div class="block-crumbs" prefix:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="https://exsample.ru/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Главная</a></span> » <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="https://'.$customlink.'">'.$customcategory.'</a></span>  »  <span class="current-crumbs"><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>'
<?php }else{
    crumbs_breadcrumbs_new();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись. Ввёл приведённый вами код:       пишет синтаксическая ошибка :-(

Comment: я там тег не открыл , поправил.

Comment: Всё равно пишет синтаксическая ошибка :-(Я отредактировал первоначальное сообщение с вопросом и прикрепил что я ввёл. Где я совершил ошибку?

Comment: Вы используете плагин ACF?

Comment: Нет, ничего подобного не использую. Но чуть ниже подключаю такой командой сайдбар: `<?php if ( is_single() ) {
    $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar", true); // левый сайдбар
    if ($sidebar)
        get_sidebar($sidebar);
    else
        get_sidebar('second');
}
    else
        get_sidebar('second');
// is_single() ?>`

Comment: Я вас запутал, извините. Первый ответ я давал по ACF так как сам его использую повсеместно, на автомате. Всё исправил.

Comment: И всё равно ругается: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)` на вот эту строчку `$id = echo get_queried_object_id();`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53911/discussion-between-kirill-korushkin-and-useruser-name).